# Weird Wine dependency problems on Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, wine, xubuntu

I'm on 64-bit Xubuntu 14.10. Nvidia graphics with the proprietary drivers, if that matters. I just ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, so I should be up to date. My CPU architecture is x86_64.

I'm trying to install PlayOnLinux. I added the PPA `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu` and just ran `apt-get install playonlinux`. Didn't work. I got this output:

```
peter@HandOfGod:~$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: wine or
                        wine-unstable but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`apt-get -f install playonlinux` has no effect. The output is as above.

Next I tried `apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install playonlinux`. This gave me a huge wall of text too long to post here. It was basically a bunch of `broken x depends on y`. It repeatedly mentioned i386 packages, which is strange because my machine is 64-bit.

`apt-cache policy playonlinux` gives this:

`playonlinux:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.3-1
  Version table:
     4.2.3-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages`

I tried to install using synaptic to see what it says.

[image: Screenshot of Synaptic]

Not good. It wants to remove about a billion packages, many completely unrelated to Wine.

Comment: Which PPA did you add, and what architecture are you using?

Comment: @Wilf: I edited the post to contain that info. It's near the top.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` and `wine --version`? Also, `aptitude` may work better than `apt-get`.